# How to store the information in react component.

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

When I am asking this question, lots of doubts are coming into my mind. well, first I will give my problem description.

I have component X. and it contains checkboxes and a search box.
[image]

while something typed (call it search_query) in search box,
 X needed to update the checkboxes which matches the search_query. [note that I got all the values of checkboxes by some api call. and it is done when component created.  ]

First doubts I came to my mind is that

1. store (search_query) and (values of checkboxes) in component state

if the values are more searching takes more time.

2. is it possible to change the values of props inside the component

or is there any other way to do it ??

Comment: You need to show your work. How is your component written?https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no code is shared. Assuming you are using plain React ( no  Redux, middlewares are used ).

Answering your question:

[1] Is it possible to change the values of props inside the component?

Changing props values inside the component is a bad approach.

"All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props."

[ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only]

Also, the view doesn't get the update if props values changed within the component.

[2] or is there any other way to do it.

yes ( without mutation inside the component )
using "state" property to hold values & setState to update values.

[3] How to store the information in react component?

Let's rename component X as FilterData,
searchbox ( SearchBox ) & checkboxes (SelectionBox) are two individual components.

```
// Define state to FilterData
class FilterData extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      searchResults: []
    }
  }
  .... 
}

// pass the state values to child components as props
class FilterData extends React.Component {
  .... 
render() {
return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox term={this.state.term}  />
        <SelectionBox options={this.state.searchResults} /> 
      </div>
    )
}
}
```

In React App, 
data flows top down (unidirectional) and there should be a single source of truth.

SearchBox & SelectionBox are two individual (sibling) components,
SearchBox's state has terms ( which has the search string )
When the user enters input SearchBox will update its state and possible to detect change event and fire ajax and get the response.

How SelectionBox can detect search that had happened, how it can get data.
This is why the state is moved to common ancestor FilterData.

[Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html]

[Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down]

Code Sample -----------------------------------------------------

Selected values are not saved:
https://codepen.io/sudhnk/pen/NgWgqe?editors=1010

Selected values are saved:
https://codepen.io/sudhnk/pen/JJjyZw?editors=1010